# Rail prepend on helper not working when using production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to add prepend to number_to_currency helper so it can accept more options.
When use on development environment, it works right.
When use on production environment, it just not works.
I tried and looked for explanations but I could not get it.

Code added to ApplicationHelper:

```
module NumberToCurrencyWithLocale
  def number_to_currency(number, options = {})
    if options[:locale]
      super(number, {:locale => options[:locale]})
    elsif (service = options.delete(:service)) and (locale = service.try(:localizacion).try(:pais).try(:idioma).try(:codigo))
      super(number, options.merge({:locale => locale}))
    else
      super(number, options)
    end
  end
end

ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper.send(:prepend, NumberToCurrencyWithLocale)
```

I'm using rails 5.0.2 and ruby 2.3.3p222
Thank you.

Comment: What error do you get, can you put some code?

Comment: Using an example:

Production environment: return $100 string
Development environment: return 100€ string

It looks like ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper.send(:prepend, NumberToCurrencyWithLocale) is not being executed on production environment